# ElasticSearch data model for analyzing logs system

Tags: elasticsearch, data-modeling, datamodel

I'm fairly new to ElasticSearch and struggle with design data models for my problem. Here some brief info:

- My system have many computers. Each computer can have few hundreds of configuration parameters. These parameters value can be different for each computer.
- A computer will have multiple type of logs. Each log can have millions line of messages. At a certain time, we can take a snapshot of these logs and configurations of each computer.
- A snapshot of logs are put in a single zip file and will be sent to a log analysis system to store and process. Each computer can have multiple snapshot files stored in the system.
- User can query info on logs and computer configurations either separately or joinly.

Can you help give me some idea to design the models for computer and logs effectively in this situation?

I looked up and thought of using parent-child relationship like this:

```
PUT /computers
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "join_fields": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "computer": ["log_type_1", "log_type_2", "log_type_3"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each document can either be computer configuration parameters or a single log message. But the biggest drawback is everything will be kept in one shard. And I affraid that can greatly affect the performance in the long run.

Another approach would be creating different indexes for computer and logs. But then how can I query for information without making multiple call to Elastic Search?

Comment: Based on what you described, I don't see why you'd need different indexes or a join type... Each of your document should simply be denormalized and contain a timestamp (at which the configuration snapshot was taken), the computer name, a configuration id, configuration fields, log type, log message, snapshot name (if applicable), anything else you can think of... then your query can simply contain whatever constraints to focus on the desired dataset to observe.

Comment: @Val thanks for replying. If I denormalize like you said, does that mean each document contains a single log message and few hundreds configuration fields/parameters? I feel like it's big waste of storage. Because there are so many messages, and each document will contain only about 1% for log, and 99% for configuration fields.